# c# reading/writing bytes to/from console

Tags: c#, console, arrays

I have a `byte[]` array and want to write it to stdout: `Console.Out.Write(arr2str(arr))`. How to convert `byte[]` to string, so that `app.exe > arr.txt` does the expected thing? I just want to save the array to a file using a pipe, but encodings mess things up.

I'd later want to read that byte array from stdin: `app.exe < arr.txt` and get the same thing.

How can I do these two things: write and read byte arrays to/from stdin/stdout?

EDIT:

I'm reading with `string s = Console.In.ReadToEnd()`, and then `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)`. I'm converting from array to string with `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes)`, but this doesn't work when used with `<`,`>`. By "doesn't work" I mean that writing and reading over a pipe does not return the same thing.

Comment: Raw bytes **should NOT** be saved to a text file. However, `>` works on `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: @ColeJohnson: imagine I'm saving to arr.bin, instead of arr.txt :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To work with binary files you want Console.OpenStandardInput() to retrieve a Stream that you can read from. This has been covered in other threads here at SO, this one for example: [Read binary data from Console.In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562417/read-binary-data-from-console-in)

Answer (score 4):

If you are writing to Console.WriteLine you need to encode the text in to a printable format. If you want to output to a file as a binary you ***can't*** use Console.WriteLine

If you still need to output to the console you either need to open the raw stream with [Console.OpenStandardOutput()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562417/read-binary-data-from-console-in) or call [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) to turn the byte array to a string. There is also [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string) to come back from base64 to a byte array.

Comment: Is there a way to do what I described without using Console.Write? Are you commenting about this specific function?

Comment: @user1367401 I have updated my answer with the stream altertinitave.