# How can you use Console.Out to write a byte[] to a file?

Tags: c#, stream, console, textwriter

In java you can do this:

```
File file = new File(filepath);
PrintStream pstream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
System.setOut(pstream);

byte[] bytes = GetBytes();
System.out.write(bytes);
```

I want to do something similar in C#. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath);
Console.SetOut(writer);

byte[] bytes = GetBytes();
Console.Out.Write(bytes);
```

It looks like the main problem here is that the Write method does not accept an array of bytes as an argument.

I know that I could get away with File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, bytes), but I would like to keep the C# code as close as possible to the original, java code.

Comment: Why not just write the bytes to the `StreamWriter` directly?  Bytes aren't written out to a console, strings are.  The Java code you have is writing a string *representation* of the byte array to the console.  You need to emulate the representation that Java uses and write that to the `StreamWriter`.

Comment: Removing the `[java]` tag as the answer won't be about java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397235/write-bytes-to-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562417/read-binary-data-from-console-in

Comment: In a nutshell, you’re simply not supposed to do that. Standard input and output are strictly for text, not for binary data.

Comment: Yes, indeed. And if you're not happy with the standard libraries, why don't you override these functions?

Comment: I also tried doing Console.Out.Write(Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes)); but I ended up with a file that contained corrupted data. I guess I'll have to play with the StreamWriter object directly

Comment: @JohnSmith, honestly, that's probably your best option. I realize that you want to make the code as 1-1 as possible with the original Java, but the fact is `Console` is not 1-1 with `System.out`. a `StreamWriter` is going to be more 1-1, logically, even if the *verbage* of the code differs. If you need the ability to hot-swap the output, you can just create a wrapper class for it and pass that around as your "out".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that I could get away with File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, bytes), but I would like to keep the C# code as close as possible to the original, java code.

The Java code does something you’re not supposed to do: it’s writing binary data to the standard output, and standard streams aren’t designed for binary data, they’re designed with text in mind. .NET does “the right thing” here and gives you a *text* interface, not a binary data interface.

The correct method is therefore to write the data to a file directly, not to standard output.

<del>As a workaround you can fake it and convert the bytes to characters using an invariant encoding for the range of `byte`:</del> Doesn’t work since the “invariant” encoding for .NET strings is UTF-16 which doesn’t accept every byte input as valid; for instance, the byte array `new byte[] { 0xFF }` is an invalid UTF-16 code sequence.

Comment: That answers my question. However, I'd like to note that the workaround you proposed does not work: Console.Out.Write(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bytes)). Are you sure 1252 is the correct code page?

Comment: 65001 is not working either. It's okay. I'll just forget about Console.Out. Thanks.

Comment: @John Windows-1252 is an 8 bit encoding that should transform each byte into a unique character. Those characters are internally UTF-16 though, and the output happens as UTF-8 so I’m not surprised that it doesn’t work. I don’t think there’s a way to get it to work actually.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan No, it should be UTF-16 (I.e. just `Encoding.Unicode`) but unfortunately that won’t work because not all byte sequences are valid UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

Not [just](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx)

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, GetBytes())
```

or you could do,

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filepath))
{
    var bytes = GetBytes();
    writer.BaseStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
};
```

Once you pass the `StreamWriter` to `SetOut` it exposes only the base `TextWriter` which does not allow access to the internal stream. This makes sense because Console is designed for providing output to the user. I guess its non standard to output arbritary binary to the console.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the method [`System.Console.OpenStandardOutput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.openstandardoutput) which retrieves the binary standard output stream. You can use that to do something like

```cs
byte[] bytes = GetBytes();
Console.OpenStandardOutput().Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```