# Event driven stdin in C#

Tags: c#, ipc, stdout, stdin

Does C# provide an event when data is received on the [stdin stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx55zca2(v=vs.110).aspx) for my own process? Something like [Process.OutputDataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx), only I need an event for InputDataReceived.

I've searched high and low, and learned to [redirect stdin->stdout](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18577/How-to-redirect-Standard-Input-Output-of-an-applic), [monitor output streams of spawned apps](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170017/Solving-Problems-of-Monitoring-Standard-Output-and) and a ton of other stuff, but nowhere has anyone shown which event is triggered when stdin is recieved. Unless I use a dumb polling loop in `main()`.

```
// dumb polling loop -- is this the only way? does this consume a lot of CPU?
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null && line != "") {
     // do work
}
```

Also, I need to get binary data from the stream, something like this:

```
using (Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput())
using (Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = stdin.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
        stdout.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want that event for a process (from the outside) or for your own process?

Comment: Why do you need this event? Unless you write a multi-threaded program, the event won't behave any differently than reading in a loop.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Understood. Thats a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polling loop won't consume much CPU, because ReadLine blocks and waits. Put this code in an own worker-thread and raise your event out of it. As far as I know, there is no such feature in .NET.

**EDIT: I was wrong here in the first place. Corrected:**

You can actually read the binary data from stdin, as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562417/read-binary-data-from-console-in) says:

> To read binary, the best approach is to use the raw input stream - here showing something like "echo" between stdin and stdout:

```
using (Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput())
using (Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = stdin.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
        stdout.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why cannot I use `stdin.Read(..)` to read binary data directly? Why is base64 needed? Are the `stdin` streams limited to ASCII characters?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong on the stdin.read-binary topic. I updated my answer.

Comment: No, they aren't. Base64 isn't needed. You can use the asynchronous methods like [ReadAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid blocking entirely and achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Can you add an answer for async reading of streams?

Comment: @Geotarget first, why do you want to do this? Unless you have another thread processing the input, asynchronously reading the data won't have any benefit

Answer (score 2):

Here's an async approach. Like OutputDataReceived, the callback runs on newlines. For binary, [streaming to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2525559/316760) might work. Switching it to a binary stream is harder because you can't just check for newline.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static void ListenToParent(Action<string> onMessageFromParent)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true) // Loop runs only once per line received
        {
            var text = await Console.In.ReadLineAsync();
            onMessageFromParent(text);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's how my parent app sets up the child process:

```
var child = new Process()
{
    EnableRaisingEvents = true,
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = ..., // .exe path
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    },
};

child.Start();
child.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

... and how it sends a line to the child process:

```
child.StandardInput.WriteLine("Message from parent");
```