# How to detect if Console.In (stdin) has been redirected?

Tags: c#, console, redirect, stdin

I want to write a console application that have a different behavior depending if the input is coming from keyboard or from, say, a file.

Is it possible? What's the most elegant way to do it in C#?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can find out by p/invoking the Windows FileType() API function.  Here's a helper class:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class ConsoleEx {
    public static bool IsOutputRedirected {
        get { return FileType.Char != GetFileType(GetStdHandle(StdHandle.Stdout)); }
    }
    public static bool IsInputRedirected {
        get { return FileType.Char != GetFileType(GetStdHandle(StdHandle.Stdin)); }
    }
    public static bool IsErrorRedirected {
        get { return FileType.Char != GetFileType(GetStdHandle(StdHandle.Stderr)); }
    }

    // P/Invoke:
    private enum FileType { Unknown, Disk, Char, Pipe };
    private enum StdHandle { Stdin = -10, Stdout = -11, Stderr = -12 };
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern FileType GetFileType(IntPtr hdl);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(StdHandle std);
}
```

Usage:

```
bool inputRedirected = ConsoleEx.IsInputRedirected;
```

---

UPDATE: these methods were added to the Console class in .NET 4.5.  Without attribution I might add :(  Simply use the corresponding method instead of this helper class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.isoutputredirected.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.isinputredirected.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.iserrorredirected.aspx

Comment: The code above was put in place for .NET 4.5 which now include properties IsErrorRedirected, IsInputRedirected and IsOutputRedirected.

Comment: interesting implementation, unfortunately it is not applicable for cross-platform development.

Comment: The isatty() function tends to be available on other platforms for a similar test.

Answer (score 8):

Interestingly, when a pipe is open, the `System.Console.WindowHeight` and `System.Console.WindowWidth` Parameters are **zero**, which I found out due to several `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`'s in code paths that did not care for the console size being zero.

**Crossplatform**: The behavior is the same under **MS dotNET** and **Mono** on Linux and Windows (I haven't tried it on a Mac).

When either STDIN or STDOUT are piped, the console size is set to 0. Thus building on Hans's implementation, my code is as follows:

```
using System;


 public static class ConsoleEx {
        public static bool IsConsoleSizeZero {
            get {
                try {
                    return (0 == (Console.WindowHeight + Console.WindowWidth));
                }
                catch (Exception exc){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        public static bool IsOutputRedirected {
            get { return IsConsoleSizeZero && !Console.KeyAvailable; }
        }
        public static bool IsInputRedirected {
            get { return IsConsoleSizeZero && Console.KeyAvailable; }
        }
}
```

***Update 2016***:
Added exception handling to the `IsConsoleSizeZero` Code to improve the usability of the code in a wider context.

The code still seems to work well, at least speaking from experience whilst using MonoDevelop / Xamarin Studio.

**Related**:

- MSDN: [KeyAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable.aspx)
- [Setting System.Console.WindowHeight throws an System.NotSupportedException under Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520753/setting-system-console-windowheight-throws-an-system-notsupportedexception-under).

Comment: Nice catch on the `Console.WindowHeight`! I'm not so sure about the use of `Console.KeyAvailable` though. For one, it's perfectly possible to redirect both input and output, and your code would not be able to detect that.

Comment: I'm running on Debian Wheezy.  The 0 == (Console.WindowHeight + Console.WindowWidth) trick works for me.  For instance, when my app is launched via monit the sum is 0.  When manually from the command prompt it is a positive number.  When running consoleless, KeyAvailable returns false but if I actually call ReadKey it yields zero.

Comment: I can confirm this _seems_ to work on Mac. Although Mono reports "Warning: Mono LIMITATION: Only works on windows" in Xamarin Studio. I can't figure out if "Windows" is misspelled (capital W), or the error is saying it doesn't work in the debugger.

Comment: this code isn't safe, Console.KeyAvailable can throw an InvalidOperationException in some cases when the input has been redirected -- so merely checking that property can crash the application

Answer (score 4):

Since framework 4.5 exists the property Console.IsInputRedirected. 8-)

See Microsoft Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.isinputredirected

Comment: Also works on .NET 5 and 6, which is really nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Lorenz answer is a good beginning, but unfortunately can be used only a inspiration. There are more modes for running a console application.

1. Standard run *(in console, without any redirection)*

   Everything work as expected in console.
2. Executing with redirection from console with standard input and/or standard output redirection

   e.g.

   `type input_file.txt | application.exe` *(in **Windows**)*, or `application.exe <input_file.txt` for input redirection

   *(replace `type` with `cat` in **Linux**)*

   *or*

   `application.exe | grep pattern` or `application.exe >output_file.txt` for output redirection

   *or*

   `type input_file.txt | application.exe | grep pattern` or `application.exe <input_file.txt >output_file.txt` for input and output redirection
3. Executing with redirection from console with standard output **and** error output redirection

   e.g. `application.exe >output_file.txt 2>error_file.txt`
4. Executing with hidden console and redirected input/output/error

   e.g. from a GUI application *(console is not Visible at all)*
5. Executing with hidden console **without** redirection of input/output/error

Each of these mode has it's own 'features'. The `Console.WindowHeight` and `Console.WindowWidth` work in ***Windows*** for the 1st and 2nd mode in the standard way. In ***Linux*** the return value in 2nd and 3rd mode is *zero*. Therefore in Linux you can not detect input only redirecting.

Therefore the code from Lorenz answer can not be used for detection of redirection in all cases. The `IOException` when reading `Console.WindowHeight` or `Console.WindowWidth` is thrown only when there is **no output** to console *(e.g. 3rd mode)* and only for ***Windows***.

To detect ***input*** redirection *(in **Windows** only)* use this function:

```
private static bool IsInputRedirected()
{
  try
  {
    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
      return (false);
    }
  }
  catch (InvalidOperationException)
  {
    return (true);
  }
  return (false);
}
```

For all other redirection and operating systems... try to experiment how to detect them. Different console properties and functions 'work' *(throw exception, or zero return values)* for different modes.

Tested on `Windows 7 .NET Framework 4 Client Profile` and `Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.1 (Debian 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4)`.

> IMPORTANT:
>
> Do not use this function for input redirecting in Linux *(detect running OS/platform, e.g. Mono for Windows)*, because it can cause more trouble when you falsely expect redirection and the redirection is not active.

Comment: This is the only solution that's worked for me so far. .NET Core 3.1 using C#. Thanks!