# Why does my code skip my Console.Read after the first one?

Tags: c#, input, user-input, skip

Okay, so here is what I have, the console runs and accepts any number for the first input and outputs all the outputs but it skips the rest of the reads after the first one. I am new to C# and want to learn so I definetly feel like I am just missing something stupid here. Do not worry about the purpose as I only want help with this problem I am facing now.

Thanks guys,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stamps
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, and welcome to the U.S. Mail Stamp Printer. Now, to print the correct stamp for your postage, please enter the number of half ounces (so 1= .5 ounce, 2 = 1 ounce) your package will weigh \n");
            double i = Console.Read();

            Console.WriteLine("Thank you, now, will you be sending to zone 1, 2, or 3? Simply enter the zone number and press enter\n");
            double z = Console.Read();

            Console.WriteLine("Great! Now, last question before I print your stamp, will you be using Local Mail or Air Mail, use the number 1 for local and the number 2 for air.\n");
            double m = Console.Read();


            if (m == 2)
            {
                double m2 = .95;


            }
            else
            {
                double m2 = .49;
            }


            if( i == 1)
            {
               double i2 = 1;
            }



            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            }
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`Console.Read` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't parse input, it only reads one character from the input stream.

Use the [`Console.ReadLine` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and parse the string that you get:

```
double i = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

or:

```
int z = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

---

If you want to handle invalid input you would use the `TryParse` methods, they will return a boolean that tell you if the parsing worked or not.

---

Side note: When you try to use the `m2` and `i2` variables you will notice that it doesn't exist. The variable is local for the code blocks in the `if` statement, so you need to declare it outside to be able to use it later:

```
double m2;
if (m == 2)
{
  m2 = .95;
}
else
{
  m2 = .49;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will get to work on that this afternoon but that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

you can flush you console buffer or you can used console.readline().

For more information refer below post which give yours question answer.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302544/flushing-system-console-read
```