# Setting System.Console.WindowHeight throws an System.NotSupportedException under Mono

Tags: exception, mono, console, c#-3.0, window

I get an `Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: Operation is not supported.` The Exception is raised under Mono using Ubuntu 11.10.

**Reading** the property **works**. The [docs](http://buttle.shangorilla.com/1.1/handlers/monodoc.ashx?link=P%3aSystem.Console.WindowHeight) could suggest that the Method does not pose issues.

Any ideas on how to best handle or fix this situation?

My **current solution** is rather awkward, and does not solve the issue of setting the Window Size through the System.Console-API:

```
        const int defaultConsoleWindowWidth = 80;
        const int defaultConsoleWindowHeight = 25;


        if (pid != PlatformID.Unix && pid != (PlatformID)128) {
            System.Console.WindowHeight = lastConsoleWindowHeight;
            System.Console.WindowWidth = defaultConsoleWindowWidth;
        }else{
            //assume *NIX system
            try {
                var p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"stty cols " + defaultConsoleWindowWidth + " rows " + lastConsoleWindowHeight, "-n")
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false
                };

                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { /*...*/}


        }
```

My **Mono version**:

```
lo@lo-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
TLS:           __thread
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  x86
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug 
LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Comment: for more information on such an issue that helped me, see this SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734906/how-to-fix-c-sharp-warning-ca1416-in-vscode)

Answer (score 5):

From the [master branch on mono on Github Console.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Console.cs):

```
[MonoLimitation ("Only works on windows")]
public static int WindowHeight {
    get { return ConsoleDriver.WindowHeight; }
        set { ConsoleDriver.WindowHeight = value; }
}
```

Notice the MonoLimitation attribute

Comment: Well, you have a solution already. However it seems that you might be able to use Console.SetWindowSize instead, it wont throw the exception but will have no effect on platforms where it isn't supported (i.e. other than Mono on Windows), alternatively you can extend The TermInfoDriver from Mono (which is used on linux)