# Why C# Console.WindowHeight keep returning error?

Tags: c#, window

My code keeps throwing an `NotSuppportedException` at the `Console.WindowHeight` line.

I was wondering why and what I could do to fix it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static int firstPlayerPadSize = 10;
static int secondPlayerPadSize = 4;
static int ballPositionX = 0;
static int ballPositionY = 0;
static bool ballDirectionUp = true; //Determines if the ball direction is up

static bool ballDirectionRight = false;
static int firstPlayerPosition = 0;
static int secondPlayerPosition = 0;
static int firstPlayerResult = 0;
static int secondPlayerResult = 0;
static Random randomGenerator = new Random();
//***************
//START MODEL
//*****************
public void Screen()
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
    Console.BufferWidth = Console.WindowWidth;
}
```

[image: error message that is showing up]

Comment: What is C about this?

Comment: Well, er, that command is not supported on your system. Seems fairly clear to me. Also, why have you tagged `c`?

Comment: Maybe his computer's compiler runs a half-step below normal (for my fellow musicians)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: this is not supported (on your OS/machine/whatever). If you read the details of the exception, you may find out if it's really `WindowHeight` or rather `BufferHeight` that throws.

Comment: You cannot use this property if your program does not have a console.  Could be a GUI app, could be a console mode app whose output got redirected.  So at a minimum you want to check Console.IsOutputRedirected.  Well, not in a game I'd assume, beware of copy/paste code.

Comment: what command would I use instead it worked on windows before?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520753/setting-system-console-windowheight-throws-an-system-notsupportedexception-under

Comment: could you post the libraries you are using? It seems that your IDE does not support that method.

Comment: @Fabulous here are the libraries using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;