# GUI working but when running from console - handle invalid IOException

Tags: c#, exception, console-application, ioexception

I have a program that is GUI that builds my project and saves the logs in some folder.
I also run it using cmd and it works fine
but when I want to redirect it - it just breaks:
[image]

it offers me to debug it - and it shows me this line :

```
  if (startPosition == 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(s);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.CursorLeft = 70; //THIS LINE
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                    }
```

can anyone help me understanding what is wring here?
thank you!

Comment: That line moves the cursor 70 spaces inwards in the command line window?

Comment: Are you redirecting Console to a file stream? If so, check that the configuration points to a valid location for the file.

Comment: You will need to avoid using properties like CursorLeft when output is redirected, there is no console.  Use the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3453272/17034) to detect that output is being redirected.

Comment: when I'm creating the log file - it works fine even when I'm using the console. but when I want to re-direct it - then it fails =\