# Can I bypass Console.ReadKey() issue when input is redirected?

Tags: c#, console.readkey

I am a C# teacher and I wrote some automated HW checker for my students.
The students write C# Console Applications. My HW checker is based on input redirection so I can test their code on my own generated input.

The problem is that students sometimes end their program with a `Console.ReadKey()` instruction (They do so just to make the execution window not close when they ran the program under F5 - Debug). The `Console.ReadKey()` crashes when ran under input redirection with the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file.

Do I have any way to "bypass" this problem (without altering the students code)? Maybe tell `Console` to ignore `ReadKey` instructions?

Comment: You can't "bypass" it.  The code has to be written so it doesn't call ReadKey() when input is redirected.  Use the [IsInputRedirected method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3453272/17034).  Or instruct the students to not use ReadKey().  Or ReadLine() for that matter.  Teaching them how to set a breakpoint at the last brace of Main() so they don't need to do that would be useful.

Comment: Use a Teensy (or anything else) to emulate a keyboard that "types" your content. Then you won't need to redirect input, so ReadKey will work!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a programmatic way of handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the executables are in IL, you can create an easy application that uses [ILDASM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1).

The key point is: disassemble the executable with ILDASM into a text file/stream, look for any call to `Console.Read` and remove it, than recompile it and run.

Answer (score 2):

I see a clear case for a Dependency Injection pattern.

Let's build a simple example, with `Read`, `ReadLine` and `WriteLine` functionalities polymorphically: your students must write a homework in which a number given in the `Console.ReadLine()` must be parsed as `int` and returned to the `Console` Window.

Usually a student writes something like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stringValue = Console.ReadLine();
        int number;

        if (int.TryParse(stringValue, out number))
            Console.WriteLine($"The double of {number} is {number * 2}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Wrong input! '{stringValue}' is not an integer!");

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Now, instead, create an `interface` for the `Console` functionalities:

```
public interface IOutput
{
    void Read();
    string ReadLine();
    void WriteLine(string text);
}
```

A student must create a `Homework` `class` that wraps all the required homework code, using an `IOutput` instance in this way:

```
public class HomeWork
{
    private IOutput _output;

    public HomeWork(IOutput output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        _output.WriteLine("Give me an integer:");

        var stringValue = _output.ReadLine();

        int number;

        if (int.TryParse(stringValue, out number))
            _output.WriteLine($"The double of {number} is {number * 2}");
        else
            _output.WriteLine($"Wrong input! '{stringValue}' is not an integer!");

        _output.Read();
    }
}
```

The `Main` becomes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var h = new HomeWork(new ConsoleOutput());
    h.Run();
}
```

You give them also the `ConsoleOutput` `class`:

```
public class ConsoleOutput : IOutput
{
    public void Read()
    {
        Console.Read();
    }

    public string ReadLine()
    {
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void WriteLine(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

So the use it instead of call directly `Console.Read()` etc.

The student must pass to you not the entire `Application`, but only the `Homework` `class`.

You can create a test class that use the `Homework` `class` with some test implementations of `IOutput` like the followings:

```
public abstract class TestOutput : IOutput
{
    public TestOutput()
    {
        Outputs = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        //do nothing?
    }

    public abstract string ReadLine();

    public void WriteLine(string text)
    {
        Outputs.Add(text);
    }

    public List<string> Outputs { get; set; }
}

public class TestOutputWithAValidNumber : TestOutput
{
    public TestOutputWithAValidNumber(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ReadLine()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }

    public int Value { get; }
}

public class TestOutputWithNotValidNumber : TestOutput
{
    public TestOutputWithNotValidNumber(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ReadLine()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public string Value { get; }
}
```

The test class can be something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestOutputClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGoodNumber()
    {
        var testOutput = new TestOutputWithAValidNumber(1234);

        var h = new HomeWork(testOutput);

        h.Run();

        Assert.AreEqual(1234, testOutput.Value);
        Assert.AreEqual("Give me an integer:", testOutput.Outputs[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual("The double of 1234 is 2468", testOutput.Outputs[1]);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestWrongNumber()
    {
        var testOutput = new TestOutputWithNotValidNumber("foo");

        var h = new HomeWork(testOutput);

        h.Run();

        Assert.AreEqual("foo", testOutput.Value);
        Assert.AreEqual("Give me an integer:", testOutput.Outputs[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual("Wrong input! 'foo' is not an integer!", testOutput.Outputs[1]);
    }
}
```

If you need only to wrap the `Console.Read()` method, feel free to simplify all this code, but IMHO I thought that a wider view on this possible solution would have been useful anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your well . Although your answer is very well explained and is the "correct" way to do this - I can not use it due to the pedagog complexity of explaining the students on interfaces & depedencies - they are just "hello World" freshmen...