# Error due Console.ReadKey() when you start Process

Tags: c#

Sorry for my english.

I need from one application to run the console application, and read all that it outputs.

program 'App.exe':

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (string arg in args)
        Console.WriteLine(arg);

    Console.ReadKey(); // problem here
}
```

program that reads

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "App.exe",
            Arguments = "1 2 3 4 5",
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        }
    };

    process.Start();

    Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When you run crashes window. Is it possible to solve the problem without changing the application code 'App.exe'?

Comment: `ReadKey` reads from the standard input, have you tried redirecting that too?

Comment: `Console.ReadKey` reads the user input of keys pressed. I believe you're looking for `Console.Read()`

Comment: No, you have to change the App code, since there lies your problem.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, it did not help

Comment: Like @RyanCarlisle said, Console.ReadKey is waiting for user input, you have CreateNoWindow set to true, how can a user send input?

Comment: To read up to the input block assign process.OutputDataReceived, call .Start() then .BeginOutputReadLine()

Comment: Use [Console.IsOutputRedirected](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3453272/17034) to know to not call ReadKey().