# c# how to detect if the console stdin is a terminal

Tags: c#, .net-standard

I am using the .net standard development console application, how would I do detect if the stdin is a terminal or pipe. So that I can optimize the interaction.

Functions similar to functions provided by `isatty`

Comment: Can this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.isinputredirected?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_IsInputRedirected

Comment: You can try if this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12527552/1220550

Comment: @ZorgoZ used IsInputRedirected, and it looks like there is no problem for the time being. thanks.