How to read piped input and use Console.ReadLine() in the same C# program?
I am trying to create a program that must accept piped input, and be able to request more input from the user afterwards. The problem is that after I read the piped input, I can no longer use Console.ReadLine() since it will always return null and won't wait for the user input.
For example, I try to execute this code :
var pipedInput = Console.In.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(pipedInput);
Console.Write("Enter input:");
var input = Console.ReadLine() ?? "NULL";
Console.WriteLine(input);

I obtain this result:
echo -n "test" | ./my_program 
test
Enter input:NULL

As we can see, the piped input is correctly read, but then I can't use Console.ReadLine() correctly.
How can I fix this ?
Thanks for your help !

How would you expect this to work? Console.In isn't going to magically get reopened after it's been closed. I would suggest changing your code to accept the name of a file with the information that you're currently piping, then you can use Console.ReadLine for interactive user input.

Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/3453220/125981

Since Console.In is a TextReader https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.in?view=net-8.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textreader.readtoend?view=net-8.0 might help you.

Maybe your actual question is an X-Y here and you want to ask "how to pipe an EOF character from the command prompt?"  (CTRL-Z)  (CTRL-D on Linux perhaps)
