# Checking Console.ReadLine()!=null

Tags: c#, null, console

I am making a CMD for my application, and figure I have a trouble when I check `Console.ReadLine != null``

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
 if(input != null)
     SomeFunction(input);
```

In `SomeFunction()`, I split this string, so for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(input[0]);
```

The problem is that it works when the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> once. But if the user hits it again, I get an exception.

That [0] does not exist.

Comment: `input[0]` is the first char of the input

Comment: what do you mean by **again** ?

Comment: input[0] is the first char of the input --- figured that. but it doesnt change the problem. problem is that i get an exception after a while of console working properly that way.

Comment: if you hit <RETURN> without any input the lenght of the string is 0 - so you cannot get the *first* character of an empty string

Comment: what do you mean by again ?

By again i mean. if u run this IF again. it will return true with exactly same input (if user hits enter)

Comment: if you hit <RETURN> without any input the lenght of the string is 0 - so you cannot get the first character of an empty string

----but it works fine if u run this block once. and will nt execute The SomeFunction()

Comment: It's not clear how you are executing the block more than once. Do you mean restarting the application, using the debugger to move the current line, is there a loop that you're not showing in your question or something else?

Comment: Oh yeah Sorry. 
i found a solution for my problem.

     `while(true)
     {
      string input = Cosnole.ReadLine();
      if(input!=null)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(input[0]);
      }

     }`

so why it did confuse me:
1) When u have first loop executing. it checks if it is null. it gives your true. that (true)input!=null

but when loop executed this line second time it was (false)input!=null


so it got me confused

SOLUTION:
` if(input.Length == 0) `

it was simple as that. sorry for dumb question:)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you hit `ENTER`, `Console.ReadLine` returns empty `string`. It doesn't return *null*. Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to check instead.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
```

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) it will return null only if you press `CTRL + Z.`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Every one!

i figured that i can just check if length of string is 0.

```
if(input.Length==0) //(Actually, will check if input.Length !=0 before calling function based on original source)
```

pretty simple. but

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)
```

works as well. every day learning something new. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    DoYourWork(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just checking for null, try checking if it is empty or null using [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) because, when you do not input anything and press `Enter`, you get an empty string which results in an

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'

Your updated full code should be as follows

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) )
{
    SomeFunction(input);
}
```