# How to fix 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Key' error in c#

Tags: c#

I was using Dictionary in C# and wanted to display a Key inputted by the user and display that key and its corresponding value if that key is present in the dictionary. Also, continue reading the lines until there is no more input.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Solution 
{
    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        string number = Console.ReadLine();
        int n;
        Int32.TryParse(number, out n);

        var phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            string phoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            phoneBook.Add(name, phoneNumber);
        }

        foreach (var pair in phoneBook)
        {
            string name = pair.Key;
            string phoneNumber = pair.Value;
        }


        string x = Console.ReadLine();
        if(!phoneBook.ContainsKey(x))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
        }
        else
        {
            string result = phoneBook[x];
            Console.Write(x);
            Console.Write("=");
            Console.Write(result);
        }
    }
}


Error message:

    Unhandled Exception:
    System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: key
      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[TKey,TValue].FindEntry (TKey key) <0x7fb28d7c9320 + 0x0023c> in <3833a6edf2074b959d3dab898627f0ac>:0 
      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[TKey,TValue].ContainsKey (TKey key) <0x7fb28d7c8cd0 + 0x00009> in <3833a6edf2074b959d3dab898627f0ac>:0 
      at Solution.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00096] in solution.cs:30 
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: key
      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[TKey,TValue].FindEntry (TKey key) <0x7fb28d7c9320 + 0x0023c> in <3833a6edf2074b959d3dab898627f0ac>:0 
      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[TKey,TValue].ContainsKey (TKey key) <0x7fb28d7c8cd0 + 0x00009> in <3833a6edf2074b959d3dab898627f0ac>:0 
      at Solution.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00096] in solution.cs:30
```

Comment: Did you debug into it and find the specific line it's being called on? If you examine the values there, you'll probably find that you're passing a null where one is not allowed to be passed.

Comment: what values are you using for each entry?.

Comment: Change the if...ContainsKey to `if(x == null || !phoneBook.ContainsKey(x))`.  The error is pointing to that line of code, I believe.  Add a comment that points to the faulting line of code (to make it easier for us), and please reformat your exception text as code (with the back-ticks removed) so that the stack is readable

Comment: @Steve Try using `Control-Z` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26338850/34092

Comment: Can you explain what are you typing for the search value? I can reproduce the stated behavior if I type CTRL+Z

Comment: Where in your code are you doing "continue reading the lines until there is no more input"? That is what is missing and why you are getting the error.

Comment: You aren't doing anything in that one for-each loop block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
class Solution 
{
    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {   
        var phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            string[] record = Console.ReadLine().Split();
            string name = record[0];
            string phoneNumber = record[1];
            phoneBook.Add(name, phoneNumber); 
        }

        string x;
        while((x = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if(phoneBook.ContainsKey(x))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x + "=" + phoneBook[x]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the final solution which worked for me.
Changes:
1. Added a `while` loop condition to avoid null search string.
2. Removed the `foreach` loop which was not needed.
3. In `for` loop for taking dictionary input used the array to store two strings in each record/entry of the dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

Change the line:

```
if(!phoneBook.ContainsKey(x))
```

to:

```
if(x == null || !phoneBook.ContainsKey(x))
```

The error is pointing to that line of code, I believe. Please add a comment that points to the faulting line of code (to make it easier for us), and please reformat your exception text as code (with the back-ticks removed) so that the stack is readable.

Comment: Given that the NRE stack points to the `ContainsKey` call on that line of code, `x` must be null in some case

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that one of your objects is `null`. Most likely one of the variables being set from a call to `Console.ReadLine`.

It is a common belief that `Console.ReadLine` cannot return `null`. This is false. It will return `null` if `Control-Z` is entered at the console.

As such, you need to check for `null` before interacting with the `Dictionary` (e.g. calls to `Add` or `ContainsKey`). Alternatively, change your `ReadLine` calls from:

```
string x = Console.ReadLine();
```

to:

```
string x = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;
```

to ensure the variable **can't** be `null`.

*Also, as an optimisation, consider using `TryGetValue` vs `ContainsKey` to avoid the later `[]` call.*

Comment: I wanted to add the note about `TryGetValue` but forgot.  A nice +1 to you!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exception when trying to **saveChanges** my dbContext on ef core and asp.net core version 2.2. I was running my project on visual studio 2022.
finally, I found out I should install **dotnet-sdk-2.2.110-win-x64.exe** and **dotnet-runtime-2.2.8-win-x64.exe**. and my problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

This error can sometimes be experienced because of the relationships of its related tables. To avoid this, typing [jsonignore] above the relation lines may solve your problem.

Comment: Could you explain how using JSON ignore attribute would solve the NULL key? Also where did you see JSON being involved?

Comment: While I was trying by myself, the program was giving the same error all the time, so I watched it with breakpoint. And I found the place that returned null, the value I found was the column of the relation table, moreover, it was a KEY but it was returning null for no reason. I thought that not recognizing the column while running the program would solve the problem. And the problem is gone

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The error in the question can happen anywhere where there is a null-guard (and in the .NET base library that's almost everywhere). Since, the question explicitly asks about keys in dictionaries the answer should be related to dictionaries with null keys. Your answer is more appropriate for a question related to working with JSON. I'll let you decide if you wanna keep your answer or (re)move it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).