# Reading from Standard Input in C#

Tags: c#, input

I'm trying to read in a text file from the command prompt in C#, via

```
program.exe < textfile.txt
```

However, I cannot find the correct way to do this.

So far, I've only been able to pass the path and the filename to string [] args and then opening the file with the StreamReader class. While this is an acceptable alternative, I've been told that the method with "<", which I suppose is a redirection of standard input, offers advantages like not requiring file handling.

Can anyone give some insight into this?

edit: Program.exe is my C# application.

Comment: I believe it's the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199528), but with the input coming from a file rather than the result of a different command

Comment: Have you tried Console.ReadLine()?

Comment: If program.exe is your C# program (it is not clear) then you'd use Console.ReadLine().  Advantages, hmm, no.  Debugging sucks.

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess I missed the most obvious answer to the problem, which is indeed Console.ReadLine().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea - the '<' symbol means the Console class reads from the file you specify, instead of reading user input from the console. When you do this, you read from it using the [Console class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx).

The advantages of reading from STDIN is that the user can either run the program as `program.exe`, and manually type the input the program is expecting, or they can run it as `program.exe < input.txt`. The only time this is a disadvantage is if you know you will always supply a file, and consider the effort of typing the '<' symbol too much...

Answer (score 2):

In a command prompt the `<` sign is one of several redirection operators. Specifically, the `<` sign is the input redirection operator. When you type this: `program.exe < textfile.txt`, you are telling the command prompt to execute `program.exe` and read the command input from a file, instead of reading input from the keyboard. In this way, the command prompt basically opens `textfile.txt` and takes its content and "stuffs it" into the keyboard buffer, so, as far as `program.exe` is concerned, the input is being read from the keyboard and has no idea you are actually "stuffing" the keyboard buffer with contents from a file.

If your program currently is reading from a file, you will need to modify your program. You no longer want to read from a file and instead read from the keyboard, using commands such as [Console.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Console.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Console.ReadKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey(v=vs.110).aspx).

As far as advantages, the advantages are minimal.