# .net core usage for ubuntu linux pipelining

Tags: c#, linux, console, .net-core, pipeline

I want to use C# net Core Console  Application in Linux Ubuntu.
And I plan to generate an HTML text using this application.

This text should be passed to a program already existed in the linux and generate a .pdf file as a result.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find pipeline operations in C# Core.

How to do the best it?

Comment: I think that this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/199534/6008532

Comment: So I can use in Linux: dotnet MyProgram.dll | pdfcreator     ???? I am not so sure....

Comment: Yes, this will work, I just tested it on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you output the result on the standard output (e.g. using `Console.WriteLine()`), you will be able to use normal Unix pipes to pipe the result to another application, just as you can with any other console application.